# RShiny Leaflet- Getting data from measure tool

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to get the results (area specifically) of when a user uses the measure tool on an RShiny Leaflet map. According to the [leaflet-measure documentation](https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure), you can subscribe to 2 events on the leaflet map named *measurestart* and *measurefinish*. I need to subscribe to these events and get the result data that the events give but I don't know how.

I have tried many different ways to subscribe to the event, but none of them are getting triggered by the map.

Here is some code that feels like it's the closest to working:

```
observeEvent(input$map1_measurefinish, {
    print("user finished measurement")
})
```

or

```
observeEvent(input$measurefinish, {
    print("user finished measurement")
})
```

The code for the leaflet in my server section looks like this:

```
output$map1 <-renderLeaflet({
      m<-leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>%...
# there's more code here but I don't think its relevant for the issue
```

What do I need to do to  1. Properly subscribe to the event to detect when a measurement is finished and  2. receive the output data to do things with in the observer method?

**Edit: Solution (as given by @NicE)**

The changes I made to my code to make it work:

Inside the leaflet added the marked code:

```
output$map1 <-renderLeaflet({
     m<-leaflet() %>%
     addMeasure() %>%
     # Start
     htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          var myMap = this;
          myMap.on('measurefinish',
          function (e) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('selectedArea', e.area);
            Shiny.onInputChange('inputtedCoordinates', e.lastCoord);
          })
        }")
     # End
```

And additionally added an observer (will do more exciting things than printing):

```
observeEvent(input$selectedArea, {
    print(paste0("area received:", input$selectedArea))
})
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. I put the code in using the tags$script(HTML()) R function but still can't get a method to receive the handler. Maybe I'm not writing the receiver right? I assumed the function name either "finish" or "click" would be the name of the method this is sending it to, or would it be something else?

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a fully reproducible example (a working shiny App in that case). Not just some snippets. ;)

Comment: @SeGa Good to know, your example you made is pretty much all that I would've made, but I will for sure remember that next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can leverage the `onRender` function to add listeners to plugin events. For example you could try:

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(-73.9, 40.75, -73.95,40.8) %>%
      addMeasure() %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          var myMap = this;
          myMap.on('measurefinish',
            function (e) {
              Shiny.onInputChange('selectedArea', e.area);
            })
        }")
```

This adds a listener on `measurefinish`, and passes the `area` to the `selectedArea` shiny input. You can change `e.area` to any fields mentionned [here](https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure#measurefinish).

Here is a MWE:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  br(),
  textOutput("areaText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(-73.9, 40.75, -73.95,40.8) %>%
      addMeasure() %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          var myMap = this;
          myMap.on('measurefinish',
            function (e) {
              Shiny.onInputChange('selectedArea', e.area);
            })
        }")
    })

  output$areaText <- renderText({
    paste("Area",input$selectedArea)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is indeed much nicer and cleaner ;) Do you know how to listen to the `measurefinish` event without the `onRender` function?

Comment: @Sega, not sure how I would do it without the `onRender` function as it is hard to get a handle on the `map` object without that function

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought it should have worked by getting the map-div by Id and adding an EventListener, but couldn't get it to work like that.

Comment: This indeed worked for me! I ended up adding a simple observer to selectedArea so I could work with the data as soon as it was inputted but otherwise this is great. (stackoverflow is telling me I can't give you the bounty for an hour by the way)

Comment: While I have the R experts here, (SeGa/NicE) if either of you two know how I could detect when the user deletes a previously created chunk of area and how much area that is, I'll gladly award you some bounty for that :) (My end goal is to determine the total area that the user has measured)

Comment: I included a small example of how you could add up all area measurements, althugh I am not detecting if the previously created area is deleted. I am just summing up all values in there. If you want to be able to reset it to zero, you would have to include seom `actionButton` + `observeEvent` qhere you reset `totalArea$sum` to NULL.

Comment: @TheMooCows237 when would you need the total area that the user has measured? Rather updating the total measured area every time a user adds/removes chunks, it is probably easier to get a total number when you need it (for ex. is there a button that will trigger a calculation where you need the total area?) -- maybe make a minimal working example to make it easier

Comment: is it possible to use on render to print an information computed from the estimated surface on the "addMeasure() panel" ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method of doing it with the `addMeasure()` function from `leaflet` and some JavaScript.

The JavaScript part could certainly be optimized with some event delegation, as the buttons are rendered dynamically. Therefore I am using a `setTimeout` function which re-evaluates every second. I'm sure this could be done in a smoother way, but I'm no JS expert. ;)

The JavaScript code waits for a click on the **Finish measurement** Button and gets the result from this HTML part `$('.js-results').children()[2].innerText`.
This is then passed to `measurefinish` with `Shiny.onInputChange` so that you can access this value in your server code with `input$measurefinish`.

*One possible solution:*

```
library(shiny)

library(leaflet)

js <- HTML("
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    var fin = document.getElementsByClassName('js-finish');
    fin[0].addEventListener('click', function eventHandler(event) {
      var area = $('.js-results').children()[2].innerText;
      Shiny.onInputChange('measurefinish', area);
    });
  }, 1000);
});
")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(js)),
  leafletOutput("map1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("area")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map1 <-renderLeaflet({
    m<-leaflet() %>%
      addMeasure() %>%
      addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery')
    m
  })


  output$area <- renderText({
    req(input$measurefinish)
    area <- input$measurefinish
    area <- gsub(pattern = "\n", "", x = area, fixed = T)
    ## Convert to numeric value 
    # area <- regmatches(area, regexpr("\\(?[0-9,.]+", area))
    # area <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",", "", area, fixed=T))
    area
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Based on your comment on @NicE's answer, I edited his code to sum up all area measurements. I am using a `reactiveValues` object where the area is summed up. To reset the total area back to 0 I use an `actionButton` with an `observeEvent` part.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  br(),
  actionButton("resetArea", label = "Reset total area to 0"),
  textOutput("areaText"),
  textOutput("areaSumText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(-73.9, 40.75, -73.95,40.8) %>%
      addMeasure() %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function(el, x) {
          var myMap = this;
          myMap.on('measurefinish',
            function (e) {
              Shiny.onInputChange('selectedArea', e.area);
            })
        }")
  })

  totalArea <- reactiveValues(sum = NULL)

  observe({
    req(input$selectedArea)
    isolate({
      if (is.null(totalArea$sum)) {
        totalArea$sum = input$selectedArea
      } else {
        totalArea$sum = totalArea$sum + input$selectedArea
      }
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$resetArea, {
    totalArea$sum = NULL
  })

  output$areaText <- renderText({
    paste("Area",input$selectedArea)
  })
  output$areaSumText <- renderText({
    req(totalArea$sum)
    paste("Sum of Area",totalArea$sum)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you take a closer look at `measurefinish`. I see that it is fired in https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/44df7d18a2618e0aeecb4145d765e597ec65878b/docs/libs/leaflet-measure/leaflet-measure.js#L7251 (and in the corresponding (referenced) min.js version), but i cant see the event when starting shiny (using `getEventListeners(document.getElementById('MAPID')` in the console,...). Simplifying the JS-call to `shinyjs::onevent("measurefinish", "MAPID", function(event){getdata...})` would be nice. Got stuck there and I am curious :) - nice answer (+1) anyway!

Comment: Yes I tried to use `measurefinish`, but also couldn't make it work with shiny nor in the console. But I'm not sure if its enough to just pass the shiny-MAPID in the console and not initiate the map completely in JS?

Comment: I tried to initiate the map solely in JS but I was also not able to fire on that event. Apparently this only works in Firefox, as `leaflet-measure.min.js` cannot be loaded in Chrome / IE or Edge..